# Cordova plugin accessing activity custom method

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins

I am currently making a Cordova plugin that will have call a method which starts a tween animation on the main activity.

`cordova.getActivity().customMethod();`

Does not work because the plugin does not know whether the method is implemented or not. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Edit: To clarify my question a little bit better: **How do I make a Cordova Plugin start an Android view-animation in the current activity?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add your plugin name to plugins.xml or config.xml(as from version 2.0.0)?

like -->

```
<plugin name="Your_plugin_name" value="packagename.Your_plugin_name"/>
```

Edit:

As you are simply calling a method in your activity,I wouldn't want to write a plugin for that...but you can do that just by getting a reference from that activity in the plugin and calling the method.After all the Plugin is implemented in native Java code.But if you have implemented **CordovaWebView**,then instead I would rather call it directly from the javascript.

In onCreate:

```
cordovaWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
cordovaWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "reference");
```

In you activity:

```
public void animate()
{
   //do animation
}
```

In JS :

```
reference.animate();
```

Do as you may like.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Yes, I just want to know how to call a method in the activity from a plugin.

Comment: I edited my question to make it a little bit clearer. I haven't done anything other than make a plugin and get it into Cordova. I'm just wondering what'd be the best approach to start an animation in the main activity.

Comment: Making my own Javascriptinterface seems like a good idea. Thanks a lot!