# Cordova 3 Android plugin - how to call a function in main activity?

Tags: java, android, plugins, cordova

**Edit: User QuickFix's answer worked for me. Code right at the bottom of this question.**

I am trying to write a Cordova 3 Android plugin that makes normal and custom Toast. However, I am just a front-end developer and very new to Cordova and Android. I am still learning and would appreciate any help you can give.

So far I have managed to do these 2 tasks individually and successfully:

1. write a function in the main activity that makes normal and custom Toast (the custom Toast is simply a RelativeLayout in /res/layout that shows an icon and some text).
2. write a Cordova plugin by following Devgirl's tutorial: [How to Write a PhoneGap 3.0 Plugin for Android](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/).

My problem now is - how do I get the plugin to call the `showCustomToast()` function in the main activity? As you can see in Code block #2 below, I ran into the problem of how to even *get* the main activity so I could call `showCustomToast()`. Here is the extract of how I am currently doing this:

```java
// Problem?
HelloCordova main = (HelloCordova) cordova.getActivity();  
main.showCustomToast(toastTitle, toastText, duration);
```

I have to cast `cordova.getActivity()` to `HelloCordova`, otherwise it won't recognise that it *has* the `showCustomToast()` function. But surely this is *not* the correct approach, although it does "work", ie, I am able to get custom Toast to show in the app. I just can't help but feel that I've gone about this completely the wrong way. It's not exactly a reusable plugin at the moment!

I would be very grateful if someone could set me on the right path of how to achieve this. For example, should I give up on the plugin completely and just [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618650/cordova-plugin-accessing-activity-custom-method) instead?

This is my first Stackoverflow question so please let me know if I should change or clarify anything. Thank you for reading!!

Here's my existing code:

**Code block #1**

This `HelloCordova` class was automatically generated when starting a new Cordova project. I added the `showCustomToast()` function.

```java
package io.cordova.hellocordova;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class HelloCordova extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")

    }
    public void showCustomToast(String toastTitleText, String toastDescText, int toastDuration) {
        Toast toast = new Toast(this);
        toast.setDuration(toastDuration);   

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View appearance = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastRoot));
        toast.setView(appearance);

        TextView toastTitle = (TextView) appearance.findViewById(R.id.toastTitle);
        toastTitle.setText(toastTitleText);

        TextView toastDesc = (TextView) appearance.findViewById(R.id.toastDescription);
        toastDesc.setText(toastDescText);

        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**Code block #2**

The Java part of the Cordova plugin.

```java
package com.example.plugins.toast;

//Problem?
import io.cordova.hellocordova.HelloCordova;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToastPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    final String LOG_TAG = "ToastLog";
    public static final String ACTION_NORMAL_TOAST = "normalToast";
    public static final String ACTION_CUSTOM_TOAST = "customToast";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        final JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
        final String toastTitle = arg_object.getString("toastTitle");
        final String toastText = arg_object.getString("toastText");
        final String toastDuration = arg_object.getString("toastDuration");

        final CallbackContext ctx = callbackContext;

        try {
            if (ACTION_NORMAL_TOAST.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Normal toast: " + toastText);

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Context context = cordova.getActivity()
                                .getApplicationContext();
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        if (toastDuration.equals("LONG")) {
                            duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration).show();
                    }
                };
                this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);

                callbackContext.success();
                return true;
            } else if (ACTION_CUSTOM_TOAST.equals(action)) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Custom toast: " + toastTitle + ": " + toastText);

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        if (toastDuration.equals("LONG")) {
                            duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        }
                        //Problem?
                        HelloCordova main = (HelloCordova) cordova
                                .getActivity();
                        main.showCustomToast(toastTitle, toastText, duration);
                        ctx.success();

                    }
                };
                this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);

                callbackContext.success();
                return true;
            }
            callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: Here is the solution that worked for me. As QuickFix mentioned in their answer below, the custom toast code is now in the plugin.**

```java
package com.example.plugins.toast;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToastPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    final String LOG_TAG = "ToastLog";
    public static final String ACTION_NORMAL_TOAST = "normalToast";
    public static final String ACTION_CUSTOM_TOAST = "customToast"; 

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        final JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
        final String toastTitle = arg_object.getString("toastTitle");
        final String toastText = arg_object.getString("toastText");
        final String toastDuration = arg_object.getString("toastDuration");

        try {
            if (ACTION_NORMAL_TOAST.equals(action)) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "[Normal toast] toastText: " + toastText);

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        if (toastDuration.equals("LONG")) {
                            duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration).show();
                    }
                };
                this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
                callbackContext.success();
                return true;

            } else if (ACTION_CUSTOM_TOAST.equals(action)) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "[Custom toast] toastTitle: " + toastTitle + "\n toastText: " + toastText);

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        if (toastDuration.equals("LONG")) {
                            duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        }

                        Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

                        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                        toast.setDuration(duration);    

                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                        Resources resources = context.getResources();                       
                        String packageName = context.getPackageName();

                        View appearance = inflater.inflate(resources.getIdentifier("toast_layout","layout",packageName),null);
                        toast.setView(appearance);

                        TextView toastTitleView = (TextView) appearance.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("toastTitle","id",packageName));
                        toastTitleView.setText(toastTitle);

                        TextView toastDesc = (TextView) appearance.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("toastDescription","id",packageName));
                        toastDesc.setText(toastText);

                        toast.show();
                    }
                };
                this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
                callbackContext.success();
                return true;

            }
            callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could put showCustomToast inside the plugin instead of inside the app?

In that case you will have to replace in the function the `R.layout.layoutname` and `R.id.viewname` with

```
getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier("layoutname","layout",getApplication().getPackageName());
```

and

```
getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier("viewname","id",getApplication().getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks @QuickFix, I had no idea you could do that! That has done the trick. For anyone needing help with a similar thing, I have updated my original question to show the code that works for me. Thanks again, I appreciate it!